# 'list' object has no attribute 'Angle'

Tags: python

everyone.
I get an error ''AttributeError: ‘list’ object has no attribute ‘Angle’ ‘’ in GH_python,wenn I use ‘‘Class’’ to define a Panel.
I have three list from a Graph

```
import numpy as np   
from math import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

PG_i_1 = np.array(PG_i_1)
PG_i_2 = np.array(PG_i_2)
PG_j = np.array(PG_j)
N = len(PG_j)
```

then I set a 'Class'

```
class PanelGeo:
    """
     the 
    """
    def __init__(self,P1,P2):
        """
        P1: the first end-point of a panel
        P2: the second end-point of a panel
        """
        self.P1 = P1
        self.P2 = P2

    def Angle(self):
        # Berechne den Winkel (in Rad)
        dx = P2[0]-P1[0]
        dy = P2[1]-P1[1]
        if dx == 0:
            if dy > 0:
                self.alpha = np.pi/2
            else:
                self.alpha = 3*np.pi/2
        else:
            self.alpha = np.arctan(dy/dx)
            if dx > 0:
                if dy >=  0:
                    pass
                else:
                    self.alpha += 2*np.pi
            else:
                self.alpha += np.pi

    def getPanelVectors(self):
        # Berechne Normalenvektor:
        self.n = np.array([np.sin(alpha), -np.cos(alpha),0])
        self.t = np.array([np.cos(alpha), np.sin(alpha),0])
        return n,t

    def getPanelTransformationMatrix(self):
        # Koordinatentransformation von global zu lokal: {P_loc} = [M] * {P_glob}
        # Transformationsmatrix
        self.M = np.matrix([[ np.cos(alpha), np.sin(alpha),0], \
                       [-np.sin(alpha), np.cos(alpha),0],\
                       [0,0,0]])
        return M
```

then I want to get the alpha from 'PanelGeo'here

```
PanelGeo = [PanelGeo(PG_i_1[i],PG_i_2[i]) for i in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    #Rotationswinkel rechnen
    alpha = PanelGeo.Angle()                 # Funktion aufrufen
```

and I am receiving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GH_CPython\PythonFileWritten_3.py", line 59, in <module>
    alpha = PanelGeo.Angle()                 # Funktion aufrufen
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'Angle'
```

Could someone give me some advice?

Comment: Do `PanelGeoList = [PanelGeo(PG_i_1[i],PG_i_2[i]) for i in range(N)]` and `PanelGeoList[i].Angle()`, you have a list not a instance of it

Comment: You are overriding the name of your class with the list. Not sure this is what you really want... Use unique names for your variables/classes/functions

Comment: Thanks all! I have get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop

```
PanelGeo = [PanelGeo(PG_i_1[i],PG_i_2[i]) for i in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    #Rotationswinkel rechnen
    alpha = PanelGeo.Angle()                 # Funktion aufrufen
```

`PanelGeo` is a `list`, not an instance of `PanelGeo`. You have to change it to:

```
panelGeos = [PanelGeo(PG_i_1[i],PG_i_2[i]) for i in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    panelGeo = panelGeos[i]
    #Rotationswinkel rechnen
    alpha = panelGeo.Angle()                 # Funktion aufrufen
```

Better yet, you can remove the need for `i` entirely:

```
panelGeos = [PanelGeo(PG_i_1[i],PG_i_2[i]) for i in range(N)]
for panelGeo in panelGeos:
    #Rotationswinkel rechnen
    alpha = panelGeo.Angle()                 # Funktion aufrufen
```

Note how I've changed the name of the list from `PanelGeo` to something else. This is because having a variable name that is the same as a class name is bound to cause confusion.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I want!